# OpenCV 2 raising exceptions on read() with different resolutions

Tags: python, opencv, video, webcam

What might be the reasons of a `cv2.VideoCapture.read()` exception?

I have an app that shows some live feed of the camera (preview frames) and after a button press it takes a snapshot with a higher resolution.

The preview frames, at `640x360` are read with no problems, but after some running time it starts to raise exceptions whenever I try to retrieve a image with `1920x1080` resolution.

Exception: `NULL object passed to Py_BuildValue`.

**OK**

```
.set(3, 640)
.set(4, 360)
```

**ERROR**

```
.set(3, 1920)
.set(4, 1080)
```

`cam.read()` can't even return False in the tuple, it just crashes.

Related code:

```
  # timer
  self.timer = QTimer()
  self.timer.timeout.connect(self.__countDown)
  self.timer.start(100)

def __countDown(self):
  self.__grabFrame()
  if self.counter == 1:
    # SHOW BACKGROUND IMAGE
  elif self.counter % 10 == 0:
    # SHOW COUNTDOWN ON SCREEN
  elif self.counter == 29:
    self.timer.stop()
    self.counter = 0
    self.camcapture.set(3, 1920)
    self.camcapture.set(4, 1080)
    self.__takePicture()
  self.counter += 1

def __grabFrame(self):
  # grab frame, transform it into image and display it inside a pixmap
  # used to show video to screen while counting down is taking place
  frame = self.camcapture.read()
  image = QImage(frame[1].data, 640, 360, QImage.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()#.mirrored(True, False)
  self.pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
  self.background.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

def __takePicture(self):
  # grab frame, transform it into image and display it inside a pixmap
  try:
    frame = self.camcapture.read()
    self.logger.info("[takePicture] Retval from camcapture.read(): {0}".format(str(frame[0])))
    image  = QImage(frame[1].data, 1920, 1080, QImage.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()
    pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
    self.pixmap = pixmap
  except Exception as e:
    self.logger.error("[takePicture] {0}".format(str(e)))
```

Comment: Have you thought about the fact that your camera does not support such resolution?

Comment: @SamFelix, it supports. I'm able to take some pictures (300 or so) with this resolution. After a period of time these exceptions starts to appear.